# Crear un servicio en RESTful Web Services

Tags: java, restful

Estoy creando un proyecto web en *NetBeans 8.02* en el momento de crear el servicio *RESTful Web Services from Entity Classes*.

Le doy a *Deploy* pero tengo un error:

> NetBeansProjects\PoliFigth\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1046: The module has not been deployed.

Si la elimino y realizo el *Deploy* nuevamente no tengo este problema.